# Unicode data sent to SqlDataAdapter trough SqlParameter doesn't return results

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to send unicode value to SqlDataAdapter trough SqlParameter to fill Dataset and i am not getting any result. I think the issue is unicode value.

I have tried adding N before parameter but with no result code sql query just doesn't work. Checked this query with unicode identifier N and it worked in MSSMS.

```
var text = "მოძებნე არაფერი";
var searchWord="მოძებნე";
var searchItem = text.Replace(searchWord, "");
searchItem.Replace(" ", "");
string select = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductImage FROM dbo.Product WHERE ProductName LIKE @name";
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, connection);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@name",
    Value = "%" + searchItem + "%",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    Size = 15
});
//var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
var ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
dataAdapter.Update(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
MessageBox.Show("done");
```

Comment: i havent tried TSQL just used SQL query. will check and update on that.

Comment: If there was any issue with Unicode this question wouldn't appear at all. SO is an ASP.NET site that stores strings in `nvarchar` fields. Strings in .NET are Unicode.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos to be fair, we would never use `SqlDataAdapter` - Dapper or EF-Core throughout

Comment: `searchItem ` has a trailing space. `searchItem.Replace(" ", "");` doesn't remove the space from `searchItem`, it creates a *new* string without it. That value though is never used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're probably on the money there; worth posting as an answer IMO

Comment: Tried code that you suggested got same result as normal sql command

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried assigning  searchItem=searchItem.Replace(" ", ""); still no result

Comment: If you were to leave off the `WHERE` clause and not set a parameter, does your grid populate? BTW, there is no point to calling `Update()` there.

Comment: @Crowcoder i had update from old code forgot to remove. will try that to.

Comment: @Crowcoder tried `string select = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductImage FROM dbo.Product WHERE ProductName LIKE '%არაფერი%'"` no result

Comment: That's not what I meant. See if your data interaction is working in general by not using a WHERE clause. Also, without `%` a LIKE is equivalent to `=`

Comment: @Crowcoder tried without where clause and also with where clause and filtered using ID and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put single quotes in %. Example: '%test%'

```
var text = "მოძებნე არაფერი";
var searchWord="მოძებნე";
var searchItem = text.Replace(searchWord, "");
searchItem.Replace(" ", "");
string select = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductImage FROM dbo.Product WHERE ProductName LIKE @name";
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, connection);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@name",
    Value = "'%" + searchItem + "%'", // Edited line
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
    Size = 15
}
);
//var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
var ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
dataAdapter.Update(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
MessageBox.Show("done");
```

I tested it here and it worked.

Regards

Comment: I have tried your suggestion no effect. Added English names to my tables and searched with them worked as expected. Unicode still doesn't return any data.

Comment: What collation are you using? Make sure the collation on your table supports unicode.

Comment: @NikaGelashvili Have you tried this `N'%' + @name + '%' `?

Example:
`WHERE ProductName LIKE N'%' + @name + '%'`;

Comment: Checked collation it is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: `string select = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductImage FROM dbo.Product WHERE ProductName LIKE N'%'+@name+'%'";` should code look like this ?

Answer (score 1):

`searchItem` has a leading space. `searchItem.Replace(" ", "");` doesn't remove the space from searchItem, it creates a new temporary string without it. That value though is never used.

To remove the first word *and* trim any whitespace, [String.Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8) can be used:

```
var searchItem = text.Replace(searchWord, "").Trim();
```

Strings in .NET are immutable. String manipulation functions don't modify the strings on which they're called, they create *new* strings.

Comment: Edited code to what you recommended. still no result.